# Loop over a do file with regression model in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I am estimating several regressions in Stata with the same functional form. I'd like to perform my estimations by looping over a .do file that contains the "program" for my regression. The (simplified) code I have attempted is as follows:

```
local vars waz haz whz cough fever diar

foreach depvar of local vars {
forvalues i = 10(5)15 {

do "Regression.do"

}
}
```

Where "Regression.do" is this code:

```
reg `depvar' distance_`i'
est store `depvar'_`i'
```

Stata returns an error message: "Error: last estimates not found." How can I amend my code so that I can execute the .do file in a loop?

Comment: Your do-file can’t see the local macro unless you pass it explicitly. See the section in [U] on arguments passed to do files.

Comment: Thank you for helping me diagnose the problem. Are there arguments aside from local that the do file would be able to see?

Comment: Global macros, although their use for this purpose is deprecated. See 16.4 at https://www.stata.com/manuals/u16.pdf for the documentation you should read.  However, the better solution is just not to use a trivial do-file.

Answer (score 1):

The do-file is hardly needed in this example. Using its contents directly avoids the problem that local macros are ... local ... meaning only visible within the same program space.

```
foreach depvar in waz haz whz cough fever diar { 
    foreach num in 10 15 { 
        reg `depvar' distance_`num'
        est store `depvar'_`num'
    }
}
```

is one way to simplify your code. although that is partly a matter of taste.

See also https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X20931028 for more on what bit you.

I see a lot of Stata code which puts content into a local macro only to take it out again just once and immediately. This is like "I have a pen. I put it in a box. I take it out of the box. I now have my pen again." Sometimes the box (meaning, local macro) is a good idea; but other times there is no gain to writing the code that way.

You do flag that you have fuller code, which is fair enough, and at some point having a do-file and passing arguments to it may appear to be better style.

As partly explained in the answer of @24thDan, you can pass arguments to a do-file, which is how a local macro's contents can become visible to and within a do-file.

You can rewrite your do-file this way

```
* regression.do 
args depvar num 
regress `depvar' distance_`num'
est store `depvar'_`num'
```

and within your loops call it with

```
do regression.do `depvar' `num'
```

As in the other answer, you can within the do-file refer to the first, second, ... arguments numbering them as `1`, `2`, and so on, but I recommend the use of `args` to map those local macros to other macros with intelligible names.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your code as suggested by @Nick Cox is best, however, to answer your question the solution is below:

main do-file

```
local vars waz haz whz cough fever diar

foreach depvar of local vars {
forvalues i = 10(5)15 {

do "Regression.do" "`i'"

}
}
```

regression.do

```
reg `depvar' distance_`1'
est store `depvar'_`1'
```

Comment: The spirit is right, but you need to pass the contents of `depvar` as well. That is, the do-file needs to see two arguments. See my revised answer.